# get n rows beyond the given row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with a column period. the value in this column will be like this, 201101, 201102, 201103,etc, 201112, 201201 etc If i give a number n and any period p, then it has to retrieve a period = p - n. That means it has to go n period before. Please help me how to do this. Im using SQL Server 2008. Period column is integer type.

Comment: So presumably if `p` = `201101` and `n`=2 you want between `201010` and `201101`? Is there exactly one row per period?

Comment: Perhaps OP wants just 201010, because he says _it has to retrieve *a* period_

Comment: For your information, period in this table will have a value in the order yyyymm. so if the given p is 200901 and n is 10, then it has to go 10 period before 200901 that is it has to go 200803. Hope you got it.

Comment: To Martin, yes i need between 201010 and 201101. yes. each row has a period.

Comment: My second query should do what you need.. well, I hope :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need, try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(
    SELECT TOP n * FROM your_table
    WHERE period < p
    ORDER BY period DESC) as tb
ORDER BY tb.period
```

My idea is first to take n periods backward (with subquery) and then take (with main query) the last record from subquery.
If you want a period (not only one record) you could use:

```
SELECT TOP n * FROM your_table
WHERE period < p
ORDER BY period DESC
```

Comment: Marco, your first will get one record which is in the position p-n. In the third query, you have used between p-n and p. If p=201101 and n=10, then p-n = 201091. There wont be any period like this na.

Comment: @Robin: I deleted that part. There was a misunderstanding because you told us _retrieve a period = p - n_. Anyway, the other query worked, so it's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, it looks like you'll need a between statement.

```
SELECT period from table where period between n and p
```

N and P are integer numbers in this case.

For further information about SQL, check out http://w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can try this ...

```
select * from your_table
where period = convert(varchar(6),dateadd(m,addnumber,convert(datetime,convert(varchar(6),startperiod)+'01')),112)
```

addnumer = month to add (positiv) or remove (negativ)

startperiod = start period

i think this is a better solution because if a period is actualy not in your table, then you would not get wrong results!